# Why do I get an empty variable with a reference to interface?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type myInterface interface {
    doFunc() bool
}

type myStruct struct {
    myValue string
    si            myInterface 
}

func newStrcut(si myInterface ) *myStruct {
    return &myStruct {si: si}
}

var myS *myStruct 

func main() {

    myS = newStrcut(&newStrcut{})
    myS.myValue = "test"
    if myS.doMyLogic() {
        return
    }

}

func (s *myStruct) doMyLogic() bool {
    fmt.Printf(s.myValue )
    s.si.doFunc()
    return false
}

func (s *myStruct) doFunc() bool {
    fmt.Printf(s.myValue)
    return false
}
```

Why do I get different values for `s.MyValue` in `doFunc` and `doMyLogic`? In doMyLogic it was `test` and in doFunc it is `""`.

Comment: After removing the unused libraries, I get `./test.go:24:21: newStrcut is not a type`. What are you intending with `myS = newStrcut(&newStrcut{})`?

Comment: I need it to do injection for the structure , it is needed for the testing

Comment: It doesn't compile, I don't know what you intend to do, so I can't reproduce your problem. If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which compiles and runs we can help. Did you mean `myS = newStrcut(&myStruct{})`?

Comment: yes myS = newStrcut(&myStruct{})

Comment: The idea is to create interface and then to use it from the tests and call to the same method that create the myValue and then send the relevant structure and I want that the value will be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jeremy covered why it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143413/14660). I think I can answer what the OP wants to do. I think there's a misunderstanding about how interfaces work. I think the OP is trying to give `myStruct` the `myInterface` interface, but interfaces are implicit.

```
type myInterface interface {
    doFunc() bool
}
```

This makes an interface `myInterface`. Things do not need to be declared to be of an interface. Anything which satisfies the interface is that interface. Anything which defines `doFunc() bool` is a `myInterface`. There's no need to declare it.

> *I want that the myValue will be the same for the same objects in the same structure* – user1365697 15 mins ago
>
> *The idea is to create interface and then to use it from the tests and call to the same method that create the myValue and then send the relevant structure* – user1365697 13 mins ago
>    [OP in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365697/user1365697)

```
type myStruct struct {
    myValue string
    si            myInterface 
}
```

This defines a struct which has a string, and it also has something which implements `myInterface`. Again, that's anything which defines `doFunc() bool`.

It's important to realize that `myStruct.si` is a totally different thing with (potentially, because it's not defined) its own `myValue`.

Instead of giving `myStruct` its own extra struct, I think what the OP intended is to give `myStruct` the `myInterface` interface. Since interfaces are implicit `myStruct` already satisfies `myInterface`. It should look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myInterface interface {
    doFunc() bool
}

type myStruct struct {
    myValue string
}

func (s myStruct) doMyLogic() bool {
    fmt.Println(s.myValue)
    s.doFunc()
    return false
}

func (s myStruct) doFunc() bool {
    fmt.Println(s.myValue)
    return false
}

func main() {
    myS := myStruct{ myValue: "test" }
    if myS.doMyLogic() {
        return
    }
}
```

Because `myStruct` has `doFunc() bool` defined it satisfies the `myInterface` interface. There's no need to add an extra field for it.

You can pass `myStruct` to anything requiring `myInterface`. That's the idea behind interfaces. Rather than making explicit declarations, anything which satisfies the interface will work. Like Duck Typing, but strict.

```
func usesMyInterface(s myInterface) bool {
    return s.doFunc()
}

func main() {
    myS := myStruct{ myValue: "test" }
    usesMyInterface(myS)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing the `MyValue` field on two different objects. Your code constructs an object, `myS`, which contains a pointer to a second object, `myS.si`.

The first contains `"test"` in the `MyValue` field. The other, since it was never set, gets the default value for strings, `""`.

Comment: why does the object ate diffrerent ? why i don't get the same value ? How I can fix it ?

Comment: I want that the value will be the same in the same objects

Comment: why the "s" in doMyLogic and in doFunc are different ?

Comment: I want that the myValue will be the same for the same objects in the same structure

Comment: The idea is to create interface and then to use it from the tests and call to the same method that create the myValue and then send the relevant structure

Comment: Schwern's answer below covers a reasonable version of what you may be trying to achieve here.